# How to clear cash go.Figure() plotly?

Tags: python, oop, plotly, plotly-python

I'm working a generic class which can plot multiple bar chart stacked or grouped with Plotly. My issue is that my function is also using the old data in my future plots, even with my `__init__()`.

Here is my code :

```py
class multiple_bar_chart:
    '''
    This class allow the user to create a multiple bar chart (stack or group)
    and add as many features as he wants.

    /!\ X column must be in the same format for each new data

    :param barmode : type of bar chart

    => add_bar : add a new bar to your plot
    => plot_plt : display your chart
    '''

    def __init__(self, figure=go.Figure(), barmode='stack'):
        self.fig = figure
        self.type_bar_chart = barmode  # group or stacked

    def add_bar(self, input_df, x_column, y_column, data_legend, color=None):
        self.fig.add_bar(name=data_legend,
                         x=input_df[x_column],
                         y=input_df[y_column],
                         marker_color=color)

    def plot_plt(self):
        self.fig.update_layout(barmode=self.type_bar_chart)
        st.markdown(download_plot(self.fig), unsafe_allow_html=True)
        st.plotly_chart(self.fig, use_container_width=True)

plot1 = multiple_bar_chart(barmode = 'stack')
plot2 = multiple_bar_chart(barmode = 'group') # This class is also using the plot1 data
```

I know that my problem comes from `go.Figure()`, but I don't know why my `__init__()` doesn't initialize it.

Does someone have an idea to solve this issue? I would be so grateful!

Also, if you have some suggestions to improve my programming skills, I'm listening! :)

Thanks and have a nice day :)